# jQuery undefined values

Tags: jquery

This error message shows up:

> id=35&field=undefined&value=undefined

I don't know why it don't read the values. This table is "generated" LIVE with jQuery.

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_tr', function() {

    var ID=$(this).attr('id');
    $("#label_"+ID).hide();
    $("#pen_"+ID).hide();
    $("#input_"+ID).show();
    }).change(function()
    {
    var ID = $(this).attr('id');
    var IID = document.getElementById("iid").value;
    var data=$("#input_"+ID).val();
    var dataString = 'id=' + IID + '&field=' + ID + '&value=' + data;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "updnames.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {
        $("#label_"+ID).html(data);
        document.getElementById("pen_"+ID).src="img/dotOK.png";
       document.getElementById("pen_"+ID).width="16";
        },
        error: function(data)
        {
        alert("Error!" + dataString);
        }
    });
    });

    // Klick innerhalb des Labels
    $(".editbox").mouseup(function()
    {
    return false
    });
    // Klick auserhalb des Inputfeldes
    $(document).mouseup(function()
    {
    $(".editbox").hide();
    $(".text").show();
    $(".pen").show();
    });
```

I want to live update a table with data.
Here is the HTML:

```
<table class="edit_tab" id="edit_tab">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>" id="iid" />

                    <tr class="edit_tr odd" id="name">
                        <td>Name:</td>
                        <td>
                        <span id="label_name" class="text">
                            <?php echo $row[3]; ?>
                        </span>
                        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row[3]; ?>" class="editbox form-control" id="input_name" style="display: none;" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="edit_pen">
                            <img src="pen.png" class="pen" id="pen_name" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr class="edit_tr" id="number">
                        <td>Nummer:</td>
                        <td>
                        <span id="label_nummer" class="text">
                            <?php echo $row[2]; ?>
                        </span>
                             <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row[2]; ?>" class="editbox form-control" id="input_nummer" style="display: none;"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="edit_pen">
                            <img src="pen.png" class="pen" id="pen_nummer" />
                        </td>
                    </tr></table>
```

Comment: You just can't use change event on a tr... why are you need it ?

Comment: Are you repeating `id`s?

Comment: Create a demo leaving out the ajax that replicates this. we have no idea what your live html looks like since you posted a bunch of php

Comment: I found this code on the web. I don't know why its use change events on "tr". What can I do to change it?

Comment: There are no repeating IDs.

Comment: which browser are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in your code is the mixture between the "on click" and the "on change" events ...

We don't have lot of details about what your function is doing and why you want to have an "on change" function used inside an "on click" function ...

If my thoughts are good, try to change your code as follow :

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_tr', function() {

var ID=$(this).attr('id');
$("#label_"+ID).hide();
$("#pen_"+ID).hide();
$("#input_"+ID).show();

// }).change(function()
// {

var ID = $(this).attr('id');
var IID = document.getElementById("iid").value;
var data=$("#input_"+ID).val();
var dataString = 'id=' + IID + '&field=' + ID + '&value=' + data;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "updnames.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
    $("#label_"+ID).html(data);
    document.getElementById("pen_"+ID).src="img/dotOK.png";
   document.getElementById("pen_"+ID).width="16";
    },
    error: function(data)
    {
    alert("Error!" + dataString);
    }
});

// });

// Klick innerhalb des Labels
$(".editbox").mouseup(function()
{
return false
});
// Klick auserhalb des Inputfeldes
$(document).mouseup(function()
{
$(".editbox").hide();
$(".text").show();
$(".pen").show();
});
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: awesome, taboubim! That works. Thanks a lot for the hint!

Comment: Glad to help :) .. Dont forget to choose as right answer ;) thx